# Copy all files matching criteria on find command with -exec

Tags: command-line, find, cp, recursive

Below are my attempts at copying all files except `.out` and `.class` files into a subdirectory titled `homework21/`. Note `homework21` is a subdirectory of the folder in which I am working in.

```
me@ice4:~/pset2$ find . -type f ! '(' -name '*.out' -o -name '*.class' ')'
./PartB.txt
./DooBee.java
./Prob8.java
./Diamond.java
./Prob10.java
./Prob11.java
./Drawing.java
./typescript
me@ice4:~/pset2$ find . -type f ! '(' -name '*.out' -o -name '*.class' ')' -exec cp -r homework21/. {} \;
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory `./PartB.txt' with directory `homework21/.'
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory `./DooBee.java' with directory `homework21/.'
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory `./Prob8.java' with directory `homework21/.'
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory `./Diamond.java' with directory `homework21/.'
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory `./Prob10.java' with directory `homework21/.'
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory `./Prob11.java' with directory `homework21/.'
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory `./Drawing.java' with directory `homework21/.'
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory `./typescript' with directory `homework21/.'
me@ice4:~/pset2$ ls homework21/
me@ice4:~/pset2$ find . -type f ! '(' -name '*.out' -o -name '*.class' ')' -exec cp homework21/. {} \;
cp: omitting directory `homework21/.'
cp: omitting directory `homework21/.'
cp: omitting directory `homework21/.'
cp: omitting directory `homework21/.'
cp: omitting directory `homework21/.'
cp: omitting directory `homework21/.'
cp: omitting directory `homework21/.'
cp: omitting directory `homework21/.'
me@ice4:~/pset2$ ls homework21/
me@ice4:~/pset2$ find . -type f ! '(' -name '*.out' -o -name '*.class' ')' -exec cp homework21/ {} \;
cp: omitting directory `homework21/'
cp: omitting directory `homework21/'
cp: omitting directory `homework21/'
cp: omitting directory `homework21/'
cp: omitting directory `homework21/'
cp: omitting directory `homework21/'
cp: omitting directory `homework21/'
cp: omitting directory `homework21/'
me@ice4:~/pset2$ find . -type f ! '(' -name '*.out' -o -name '*.class' ')' -exec cp -r homework21/ {} \;
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory `./PartB.txt' with directory `homework21/'
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory `./DooBee.java' with directory `homework21/'
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory `./Prob8.java' with directory `homework21/'
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory `./Diamond.java' with directory `homework21/'
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory `./Prob10.java' with directory `homework21/'
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory `./Prob11.java' with directory `homework21/'
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory `./Drawing.java' with directory `homework21/'
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory `./typescript' with directory `homework21/'
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the cp command is:

```
cp source target
```

Therefor use this `find` command:

```
find . -type f ! '(' -name '*.out' -o -name '*.class' ')' -exec cp -v {} homework21/ \;
```

Notice, the `-r` flag in `cp` is not necessary, since you're only copying files not directories. I added `-v` instead that `cp` is verbose.

Comment: +1. or end the `find` command with a `+` instead of `\;` to run only one `cp` rather than one per file to be copied.

Comment: @cos This won't work if `{}` is not the last argument. With GNU cp therer is the `-t` flag and it would work: `-exec cp -t target {} +` But without `-t` not.

Comment: `cp` have more syntaxes. E.g. `cp -t target source(s)`. In this form you can use it in `find … -exec cp -t homework21 {} +` which more effictive because use just 1 call of `cp` for many files

Comment: you can do it with xargs too: `find . -type f ! '(' -name '*.out' -o -name '*.class' ')' -print0 | xargs -0r  echo cp -v | sed -e 's/$/ homework21\//' | sh`

Comment: on second thoughts, that will fail unpleasantly if there are spaces or other problematic characters in the filenames found.  the `sed ... | sh` defeats the purpose of using `-print0`.

Comment: @cas useless example: much unnecessary invocations of sh, sed, xargs … You should choice which one you will use but not both. The task can be done in two command why you offer to call 5?

Comment: why? in my world, it's perfectly normal and correct to use exactly the tools that will do the job, no matter whether that's one tool, two tools, three tools, or (hyperbole) a thousand tools.  The example i gave was no good, but not because i used 'much unnecessary invocations of ...'

Comment: and, btw, it can be made to work by inserting yet another `sed` between `find` and `xargs` instead of using  -print0 and -0: `find ... -print | sed -r -e "s/'/\\'/g ; s/^|$/'/g" | xargs -d '\n' ... | sed ... | sh`.  A more complicated pipeline, but much more efficient execution of the `cp` command, especially if `find` finds hundreds or thousands of files.  The only thing it can't cope with is filenames with `\n` in them...theoretically possible but so pathologically rare that if you're worried about it, you should rename them to something more sane first, perhaps  s/\n/ /g